# boost aligned_allocator alignment parameter does not affect the actual alignment

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, boost, allocator

I am using *boost::alignment::aligned_allocator* in order to get the elements of my vector aligned.

However, I noticed a behavior I cannot explain within the documentation: if I specify the alignment through the keyword *alignas*, it works as expect, but not if I use the template parameter of the allocator.

Actually, I cannot find the reason of this tempoate parameter, it doesn't seem to have *any* influence on the actual alignment (i.e. if I have *alignas(64)* and 16 as alignment template parameter, it will use 64 anyway).

I tested the following code with g++ 4.9 and clang 3.6 and got the same output. Both As and Bs should be aligned. But B objects are not aligned at all.

Thanks !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/align/aligned_allocator.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct alignas(64) A { };
struct B { };

template <int _AlignT = 64, typename _ContainerT>
bool is_aligned(_ContainerT&& c)
{
    return all_of(begin(c), end(c), [](auto& e) { return (ptrdiff_t)&e % _AlignT == 0; });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A, boost::alignment::aligned_allocator<A>> va(3);
    cout << "A aligned:" << boolalpha << is_aligned(va) << endl;

    std::vector<B, boost::alignment::aligned_allocator<B, 64>> vb(3);
    cout << "B aligned:" << boolalpha << is_aligned(vb) << endl;

    for_each(begin(vb), end(vb), [](auto& e) { cout << (void*)&e << endl; });

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A aligned:true
B aligned:false
0xaeb180
0xaeb181
0xaeb182
```

Comment: It's not `aligned_allocator`, it's the approach `std::vector` uses to put values into allocated memory chunks.

Comment: `aligned_allocator` seems to make the allocated *block* align as specified, but not the individual elements in the block.

Answer (score 2):

As it has been pointed out in the comments, _boost::alignment::aligned_allocator_ is indeed in charge of the alignment of the *elements* - i.e. the entire chunk of memory used by std::vector - but not *each of the elements*.

In order to have all the elements of the std::vector that are aligned but not only the first one, **both alignas and the alignment template parameter** have to be used.

Here is an example that clearly illustrates that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/align/aligned_allocator.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct alignas(64) A { };
struct B { };

template <int _AlignT = 64, typename _ContainerT>
bool is_aligned(_ContainerT&& c)
{
    return all_of(begin(c), end(c), [](auto& e) { return (ptrdiff_t)&e % _AlignT == 0; });
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::vector<A> vc(1);
        cout << "vector<A> aligned: " << boolalpha << is_aligned(vc) << endl;
        vc.resize(3);
        cout << "vector<A>'s elements aligned: " << boolalpha << is_aligned(vc) << endl;
    }

    {
        std::vector<B, boost::alignment::aligned_allocator<B, 64>> ve(1);
        cout << "vector<B, aligned_alloc> aligned: " << boolalpha << is_aligned(ve) << endl;
        ve.resize(3);
        cout << "vector<B, aligned_alloc>'s elements aligned: " << boolalpha << is_aligned(ve) << endl;
    }

    {
        std::vector<A, boost::alignment::aligned_allocator<A, 64>> vd(3);
        cout << "vector<A, aligned_alloc> aligned: " << boolalpha << is_aligned(vd) << endl;
        vd.resize(3);
        cout << "vector<A, aligned_alloc>'s elements aligned: " << boolalpha << is_aligned(vd) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
vector<A> aligned: false
vector<A>'s elements aligned: false
vector<B, aligned_alloc> aligned: true
vector<B, aligned_alloc>'s elements aligned: false
vector<A, aligned_alloc> aligned: true
vector<A, aligned_alloc>'s elements aligned: true
```

Note that in the case of the *std::vector*, as I specified *alignas(64)*, the container itself is not aligned, but the distance between each element is 64 bytes:

```
vector<A> element: 0x75b060
vector<A> element: 0x75b0a0
vector<A> element: 0x75b0e0
```